# Column sum of multiple columns of dynamic gridview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Dynamic asp Gridview with all columns as template feild TextBox. The columns of the Gridview are also dynamic and column count may vary everytime.

Please find code below

```
public void FillPoDetails()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();           
    dt = pmdata.createdatatable(int.Parse(Session["OurStyleid"].ToString()), int.Parse(Session["PoPackid"].ToString()));
    GenerateTable(dt.Columns.Count, dt.Rows.Count,dt);
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        //Declare the bound field and allocate memory for the bound field.
        TemplateField bfield = new TemplateField();

        //Initalize the DataField value.
        bfield.HeaderTemplate = new ArtWebApp.Controls.GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, col.ColumnName);

        //Initialize the HeaderText field value.
        bfield.ItemTemplate = new ArtWebApp.Controls.GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, col.ColumnName);

        //Add the newly created bound field to the GridView.
        GrdDynamic.Columns.Add(bfield);
    }
    GrdDynamic.DataSource = dt;    
    GrdDynamic.DataBind();  
}
public GridViewTemplate(ListItemType type, string colname)
{
    //Stores the template type.
    _templateType = type;

    //Stores the column name.
    _columnName = colname;
}

void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    switch (_templateType)
    {
        case ListItemType.Header:
            //Creates a new label control and add it to the container.
            Label lbl = new Label();            
            //Allocates the new label object.
            lbl.Text = _columnName;
            lbl.CssClass = "Headerclass";
            //Assigns the name of the column in the lable.
            container.Controls.Add(lbl);        
            //Adds the newly created label control to the container.
            break;
        case ListItemType.Item:
            //Creates a new text box control and add it to the container.
            TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();                            
            //Allocates the new text box object.
            tb1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(tb1_DataBinding);    
            //Attaches the data binding event.
            tb1.Columns =6;
            //Creates a column with size 4.
            // tb1.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
            tb1.Width = 100;
            tb1.Wrap = true;
            tb1.ID = "txt_" + _columnName;
            if(_columnName== "ColorTotal")
            {
                tb1.CssClass = "ColorTotal";
            }
            else if (_columnName == "Color")
            {
                tb1.CssClass = "Color";
            }
            else
            {
                tb1.CssClass = "txtCalQty";
                tb1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isNumberKey(event,this)");
                tb1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "sumofQty(this)");
            }                       
            container.Controls.Add(tb1);                            
            //Adds the newly created textbox to the container.  
            break;
    }
}
```

And inorder to get the  row total I had added a Javascript function on keydown event and its working clearly

```
 //calculate the sum of qty on keypress
   function sumofQty(objText) {


       var cell = objText.parentNode;

       var row = cell.parentNode;

       var sum = 0;
       var textboxs = row.getElementsByClassName("txtCalQty");

       for (var i = 0; i < textboxs.length; i++)
       {
           sum += parseFloat(textboxs[i].value);
       }
       var textboxtotalqtys = row.getElementsByClassName("ColorTotal");
       textboxtotalqtys[0].value = sum.toString();         

   }
```

And the result is Like below
[image]

can anyone please help me in finding out the sum of each columns(all same cssclass).and display it in the Sizetotal row because I am not able to loop through columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give every textbox a row id and a column id through [html5 data attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). and in javascript (jQuery) filter the textboxes through column id.

example:

```
..
var sum = 0;
$( "input[data-column-id='" + selectedColumnId + "']" ).each(function( index )
{ 
   sum += parseFloat($( this ).val() );
});
..
```

By the way, use jQuery. its amazing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way.

Add Footer and Label to each Column, Then do calculations from database side best is use `LINQ` and Group by, find footer Label Controls for each column and Bind values to those Footer's Label Control, in this way your UI will have less load.

See here for code:

**.ASPX Page in Grid:**

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
   <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTotal" Text='<%#Eval("Total") %>' runat="server"> </asp:Literal> // For Sub Total
</ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
 <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltrlGrandTotal" runat="server"> // This is Grand Total
  </asp:Literal></strong>
 </FooterTemplate>                       
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# Code:**

```
 var searchResult = soService.SearchResult(companyId);
            var grandTotal = searchResult.Select(so => so.Total).Sum();
            searchResult.All(aa => aa.GrandTotal == grandTotal);

            gridSo.DataSource = searchResult;
            gridSo.DataBind();

            if (searchResult.Count > 0)
            {
                Literal ltrlGrandTotal = gridSo.FooterRow.FindControl("ltrlGrandTotal") as Literal;
                if (ltrlGrandTotal != null)
                    ltrlGrandTotal.Text = string.Format("Grand Total : $ {0}", grandTotal);
            }
```

Comment: Hi Shyam But the gridview is dynamic and again the calculation should happen each time when the value in the column is changed by client

Comment: can you please provide that jquery example

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your requirement but this may help you, After binding data to grid, once again loop through the column list

```
GrdDynamic.DataSource = dt;    
GrdDynamic.DataBind();
int rowIndex=2;
GrdDynamic.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = "Total";
GrdDynamic.FooterRow.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
   decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>(col.Caption));
   GrdDynamic.FooterRow.Cells[rowIndex++].Text = total.ToString("N2");
}
```